# refreshing grid after update does not work

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the following kendo grid, after update I want my grid to be refreshed again, from datasource,but does not work with the following approach im not sure if imm putting the refresh datasource command in the right place,any help will be highly appreciated

```
 dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        transport: {
                            read: function (options) {
                                options.success(result); // where data is the local data array
                            },
                            update: function (options) {

                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "/AdminTool/update_grid",
                                    data: options.data.models[0],
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    success: function (data) {
                                        options.success(data);
                                        // alert("success");
                                        $("#turbingrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();

                                    },
                                    error: function (data) {
                                        options.error(data);
                                        //  alert("error");
                                    },
                                });

                            },

                            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                    return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        batch:true,
                        pageSize: 40,
                        schema: {
                            //data: employee,
                            model: {
                                id: "DeviceIP",
                                fields: {
                                    DeviceIP: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                    //Producer: { type:"string" },
                                    //3 Model: { type: "string" },
                                    DeviceType:{ type:"string" },
                                    Description:{ type:"string" },
                                    Username:{ type:"string" },
                                    Password:{ type:"string" },
                                    PublicIP: { type: "string" },
                                    ModelProducer: { type: "string" },
                                    TurbineId: {type:"string"}
                                    //UnitPrice: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1} },
                                    //Discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
                                    //UnitsInStock: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0, required: true } }
                                }
                            }
                        }


                    });
```

Comment: Is this line suposed to update the datatable? `$("#turbingrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();`

Comment: @Daniel yes its

Comment: Depending on your version, [this might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399805/reloading-refreshing-kendo-grid), have you already tried it?

Comment: @Daniel where should I put this code?

Comment: It depends, options.success is a `synchronous` or an `asynchronous` function?

Comment: @Daniel I left it default,so I don't know by default which one it is,please give me a approach for either way,then ill try

Comment: I'm trying to find out in the documentation! Do you know the documentation link or something?

Comment: options.success seems to be a `synchronous` call.

Have you tried to use the `DataSource` instance reference you just created in the js? this: `var dataSource = new..`, instead of getting the instance via jQuery, couldn't you just use: `dataSource.read();`?

Comment: I believe I already know what we're missing!

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
$("#turbingrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(data);
```

instead of

```
$("#turbingrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```

to load the retrieved data to kendo Grid. Hope it helps.

Comment: where should I put it?

Comment: just where you put $("#turbingrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();

Comment: In my case I have never updated kendo datasource your way. I just initiate the ajax call alone, and then update the grid with the code above.

Comment: JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'slice'   I get this

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32104024/kendo-grid-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-slice